# Google app engine endless redirect with a filter mapped to /*

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I have a simple web app that uses basic jsp's and servlets. 
I have a servlet-filter mapped to /*. 
I have a welcome file configured to index.jsp

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

...

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

The problem I am having is when a request for a resource that doesn't exist and should return a 404 error when deployed on the app engine returns a 302 endlessly while trying to append a slash + the welcome file repeatedly.

E.G:
A request for http://myyapp.appspot.com/foo (where there is nothing configured for foo) yeilds the following:

http://myyapp.appspot.com/foo/index.jsp/index.jsp/index.jsp/index.jsp/index.jsp/index.jsp/index.jsp/index.jsp/index.jsp/index.jsp/index.jsp/index.jsp/index.jsp/index.jsp/index.jsp/index.jsp/index.jsp/index.jsp/index.jsp/index.jsp/

On the development server this returns the expected 404. If I remove the filter mapping it also returns the 404 on the app engine.

This seems fairly basic, so I am guessing I have missed something somewhere. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you know who is doing the redirecting? Welcome-list-file alone does not.

Comment: Do you use this filter just to register classes with objectify?

Comment: There must be some extra piece of information missing.  ObjectifyFilter won't issue any kind of redirect (go ahead and look at the code), nor with GAE without special prodding.

Comment: I do not know what is doing the redirecting. I am assuming its an app-engine webserver/appserver. As I mentioned it works as expected locally on the development server.

Comment: I have tried it with a simple filter as well that does nothing but `chain.doFilter(request, response);` and get the same result.
As stickfigure mentioned the ObjectifyFilter doesn't really do much either and simply passes things along.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one essential ingredient to the problem is the jsp-config tag in web.xml. Although I think the content does not matter, mine looked like this:

```
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

Removing the jsp-config tag resolved the problem for me, i.e. it is a workaround. In my case it did not hurt much, because I can specify the page encoding on each page separately. However I am still interested in a real solution.

Comment: Interesting catch...
I have the following jsp configuration :
`<jsp-config>
        <jsp-property-group>
            <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
            <scripting-invalid>true</scripting-invalid>
        </jsp-property-group>
    </jsp-config>
`
And the *workaround* I have used is to not reference any .jsp files in the app.. meaning I have lots of things like 
`<servlet>
        <servlet-name>about</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/about.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
`